# Django why getting MultiValueDictKeyError?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

here is my code:

```
 if request.method == "POST":
       forms = GoogleAuthFroms(request.POST or None) 
       if forms.is_valid(): 
            code = request.POST["auth_code"]
            
    context = {
        
        'forms':forms,
         
    }
    return render(request,'members/security.html',context)
```

This line of code `code = request.POST["auth_code"]` throwing this error `MultiValueDictKeyError at /security/ 'auth_code'`

Comment: because auth_code is not in the request.POST

Comment: @Dimitris Kougioumtzis I am not understanding. can you please explain why auth_code is not in the request.POST. I am passing the context forms where I have fields name auth_code

Comment: update your question with  the code of GoogleAuthFroms

Answer (score 1):

If the code field is already in the form there's no need in repeating it,  in your post request.POST and also you don't put a request.POST (code = request.POST["auth_code"] ) right below the form validation condition test.

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        forms = GoogleAuthFroms(request.POST or None) 
        code = request.POST.get("auth_code")
        if forms.is_valid():
            forms.save()
            return redirect(...)#You will need to redirect to a url after the form is validated and save 
        else:
            forms = GoogleAuthFroms()
    context = {
        'forms':forms,     
    }
    return render(request,'members/security.html',context)
```

Comment: You will need to redirect your form after a successful validation!